# Java: create List of List of Maps

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

I have  List of Maps and map contains json objects  ...  I have create separate lists for each json objects which has same service name means in below example if list size should be size equal to `serviceNameList`   and I want create separate list for it

means ideal scenario should be

```
List<List<Map<String, String>>> lst =new ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>();

List<Map<String, String>> serviceInfoList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>()
ArrayList<String> serviceNameList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < serviceInfoList.size(); i++) {
            Map<String, String> serviceInfoMp = new HashMap<String, String>();
            serviceInfoMp = serviceInfoList.get(i);

            Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> serviceInfoSet = serviceInfoMp.entrySet();

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> mapentry : serviceInfoSet) {
              if (mapentry.getKey().equals("serviceName")) {
                    serviceNameList.add(mapentry.getValue());
                }
             }
        }
```

map contains JSON data

means create separate list for each service name form below json and store it in list

```
{
  "ServiceData": {
    "ServiceInfo": [     
      {
        "trav": "20200131T173017Z",
        "real": "MyService",
        "lintruntime": "7",
        "upload": "184",
        "build": "1717",
        "buildproductruntime": "1709",
        "EXITCODE": "0",
        "totaltime": "3610"
      },
 {
        "trav": "20200131T173017Z",
        "real": "MyService",
        "lintruntime": "7",
        "upload": "184",
        "build": "1717",
        "buildproductruntime": "1709",
        "EXITCODE": "0",
        "totaltime": "3610"
      },
      {
        "trav": "20200131T173024Z",
        "real": "ERSampleService1",
        "lintruntime": "38",
        "upload": "381",
        "build": "1765",
        "buildproductruntime": "1767",
        "EXITCODE": "0",
        "totaltime": "3913"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

means from above Json I want list which is in size two since two service name ERSampleService1 and "MyService"

ans this list should contain list of maps coating JSON data .

basically I want to create list for each service info ..

I know Question may be confusing

But I am stuck here ...

anyone knows how to do it

In short creation of list of list of maps and traversing through it,

any help is appreciated

Comment: Thanks for sharing. What is your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll first want to create the outer most list.
Then, for each service info, you'll add a list to that outer list. 
And for each json object for that service info, you'll create a map, and then put that map into the inner list. You'll end up with something similar to this.

```
List<List<Map<String, String>>> outerList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(ServiceInfo so : serviceInfos){
        List<Map<String, String>> innerList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(JsonObject j : getJsonObjectsForThisServiceInfo(so)){
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            // Fill in the map with what you need
            // ...
            innerList.add(map);
        }
        outerList.add(innerList);

    }
//Use your new list after here for whatever you want :)
```